# Scroll view with an image is not scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll

i added an image to the scroll view. but its not scrolling...
 pls help out what is the problem..

Thanks.

```
boxImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 372)];
        boxImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chapter1box.png"];
        textScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 175, 320, 755)];
        scrollTextImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 775)];
        scrollTextImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chapter1narrationtext.png"];
        textScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        textScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
        textScroll.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
        textScroll.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        textScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 775);
        [self.view addSubview:boxImage];
        [boxImage addSubview:textScroll];
        [textScroll addSubview:scrollTextImg];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code i add the scrollview to an image view
i added it to the self.view its working now.

cant we add a scroll view to an imageview..?

Answer (score 4):

`UIImageView` has `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO` by default. Adding

```
boxImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

should help.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll view size has to be smaller than the size of it's content for scrolling to work.

Comment: the scroll view size is 320*755 and content size is 320*775.. is there in code..?